# 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0' error only when calling WCF REST method via the Internet

Tags: json, wcf, rest, sharepoint, json.net

In our SharePoint 2013 Dev Machine, I have a WCF Rest web service that can be access via the a class library. The class library has the 'Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5' installed successfully via nuget.org (Package Manager Console). The solution builds without any issue.

My SharePoint site has 2 way of being connected:

- **Local Network**: When accessed this way, the WCF REST method call works smooth. I get the correct results as well.
- **Internet Access**: We have alternative access mapping and when the WCF Rest method is called, I get the below mentioned error:

> Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Note:** Web application/bin folder has correct .dll version (6.0.5.17707)

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution:**

I had extended my web application to map to the internet (Alternative access mapping), which meant that I had a new bin folder for the new port. Once I copied and pasted the Dlls to the new bin. The error vanished.